Person buried up to neck on beach, chainsaw, footprints of invisible creature
Okay, I don't have much information about this movie since I saw it as a kid and I don't remember much. 
The only thing I can remember is a beach scene towards the end of the movie where this person was buried up their neck on the beach and I guess later someone comes with a chainsaw and slowly lowers it down towards the person's head. (Hint: It's not Creepshow! This movie was creepier!)
The next thing I can remember was a part of the movie where there were footprints being made by someone/thing invisible. Also I remember the movie being almost silent at parts (not sure if this was the movie or the VCR I was watching it on at the time).
Again, it's NONE of these:
Creepshow, Slaughterhouse-Five, Hotel Hell, Tales of the Crypt, Blood Beach (This was kinda close, but definitely not it), House/House 2
I really hope you guys know, it's been driving me crazy for months. :)

it sounds a little bit like Humongous http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082537/  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7m3QWucNxI

This one becomes a good identify question because of all of the movies you have eliminated as possibilities. Good job!

Sounds like Bloody New Year from 1987. From IMDb:

Five shipwrecked English teenagers take refuge in an island hotel that is decorated for New Years. The problem is, it's early summer, and soon enough, even the walls themselves are striking out against them...

You can see a still from the scene you've mentioned with a guy buried up to his neck in this review (though it's a weedwhacker, not a chainsaw), and also:

a group of ghosts chase two characters on the beach, and their supernatural presence is only evident through footprints on the sand.

Here's the trailer:



